# How to distinguish last float value in a list of float

Tags: c++, bison, yacc

I want to make a grammar to parse a line which contain space separated float values and string value.It is guaranteed that Last value would be float and it may be wrap in braces `{}`

Basically I want to store all values except last value in a list of string and last float value in a separate variable .

There are few examples which i want to parse :

```
example 1:
12 13 14

example 2
12 a b 15

example 3
12 13 14 {14}
```

I made grammar like this:

```
list
:FloatStringList value
{
    StoreList($1);
    StoreLastValue($2);
}


FloatStringList
:FloatStringList FloatString
{        
    $1->push_back($2);
    $$=$1;
}
|FloatString
{

    $$=new ListOfString();
    $$->push_back($1);
}
;

FloatString
:STRING
{
    $$=$1;
}
|FLOAT
{
    $$ = ConvertFloatToSring($1);
};

value
:FLOAT
{
    $$ = $1;
}
```

It works if last value is having braces but how can I differentiate between values if there is no bracket in last value.
It is also giving reduce/reduce error

Comment: read entire line as strings, count strings -> n , and then process n-1 strings as usuall, and the last string handle separatelly. also you can read ahead 1 value and if there is none it is the end of line ...

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you will need recursion.  Just treat the last value of the list as its own distinct type.  Here's a sample that is roughly what you're aiming for:

```
list: items lastValue {$1->pushBack($2);}
    ;

items: items value {$1->pushBack($2);}
    | value       {$$ = new List(); $$->pushBack($1);}
    | /* empty */ {$$ = new List();}
    ;

lastValue: '{' float '}' { $$ = parseFloat($2); }
    | float              { $$ = parseFloat($1); }
    ;

value: float         { ... }
    | string         { ... }
    ;
```

Comment: But this would result in `reduce/reduce` warnings because `items` and `value` are of same type and parser would able to distinguish between them

Comment: `items` is a list and `value` is an element.